# I'm trying to retrieve text from a textbox and convert it into rows for a datagridview

Tags: datagridview

The textbox3 should take mobile numbers(12 digits to allow country codes) and then populate it in the 2nd row of the datagridview. the first row is a reverse serial number that I have had coded.

I have tried various methods.

```
public char[] c;

public void addMobile()
    {
        //char[] i = c;


        List<string> columnheader = new List<string>();
        columnheader.Add("12");
        columnheader.Add("11");
        columnheader.Add("10");
        columnheader.Add("9");
        columnheader.Add("8");
        columnheader.Add("7");
        columnheader.Add("6");
        columnheader.Add("5");
        columnheader.Add("4");
        columnheader.Add("3");
        columnheader.Add("2");
        columnheader.Add("1");


        /*
        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 12;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = columnheader;
        */


        DataGridViewColumn newColumn;
        //dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 12;

        foreach (var item in columnheader)
        {

            newColumn = new DataGridViewColumn();
            newColumn.HeaderText = item;
            newColumn.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell(); ;
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(newColumn);
        }


        DataGridViewRow dgvRow;
        try
        {
            for (int temp = 0; temp < c.Length; temp++)
            {
                string[] data = new string[12];
                data[temp] = c[temp].ToString();
                int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[temp].Value = data[temp];
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        { 

        }
        //int row;

        /*
        for (var row = 0; row < c.Length; row++)
        {
            dgvRow = new DataGridViewRow();
            dgvRow.Cells[row].Value = c[row];
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dgvRow);
        }
         */
        /*
        try
        {
            foreach (var item in c)
            {

                dgvRow = new DataGridViewRow();
                dgvRow.SetValues(item.ToString());
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dgvRow);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { 

        }
         * */
    }
private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textBox3.Text, "[^0-9]"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter only numbers.");
            textBox3.Text.Remove(textBox3.Text.Length - 1);

            c = textBox3.Text.ToCharArray();
        }
    }
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        addMobile();
        //MessageBox.Show("Your Star Sign is " + s);
        //PatternMatch(c);
    }
```

I have added the related code snippet. The commented part is the various ways I tried or rather messed up.

Comment: Anyone online... I have been up all night stuck on this one and might just doze off in a while....

Comment: No distractions, no chit-chat (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)), asking for help, nor telling us that low rep users cannot post images is information that should be part of a post.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues happening here.

1. Your character array is only being filled when the user enters incorrect data into the textbox. - Not as intended.
2. You are re-adding the same columns every time the button is clicked - not just the first time.
3. You create a new row, then attempt to access its cells, but no cells exist.

**Issue 1 Fix**

```c
private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textBox3.Text, "[^0-9]"))
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter only numbers.");
    textBox3.Text.Remove(textBox3.Text.Length - 1);
  }
  else // Only numbers were entered.  Fill the char array.
  {
    c = textBox3.Text.ToCharArray();
  }
}
```

**Issue 2 & 3 Fix**

```c
public void addMobile()
{
  List<string> columnheader = new List<string>();
  for (int i = 12; i > 0; i--)
  {
    columnheader.Add(i.ToString());
  }

  DataGridViewColumn newColumn;

  foreach (var item in columnheader)
  {
    newColumn = new DataGridViewColumn();
    newColumn.Name = item; // Give the column its unique name.
    newColumn.HeaderText = item;
    newColumn.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();

    // Only add the column if a column of the same name doesn't already exist.
    // Prevents duplicates.
    if (!dataGridView1.Columns.Contains(newColumn.Name))
    {
      dataGridView1.Columns.Add(newColumn);
    }
  }

  DataGridViewRow dgvRow;
  dgvRow = new DataGridViewRow(); // New row - has no cells.
  dgvRow.CreateCells(dataGridView1); // Create cells matching the dgv columns.

  for (var row = 0; row < c.Length; row++)
  {
      dgvRow.Cells[row].Value = c[row];
  }

  // Add the rows outside of the forloop.
  // Otherwise you'll get a new row containing only one value, for each of the 12 digits.
  dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dgvRow);
}
```

**Extra Fix**

Note: you will run into issues if the user enters a number longer than 12 digits.  You should handle that.  For example:

```c
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (c.Length != 12)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Number isn't 12 digits.");
  }
  else
  {
    addMobile();
  }
}
```

Side note: I'm not sure why you want to add each digit to a separate column.  A single phone-number column with a format mask would be much more readable and practical.